# How can I use bootstrap with cloudflare apps

Tags: cloudflare-apps

I have tried adding bootstrap css to the install.json file the following way, but I got an error:

```
,
      {
        "type": "style",
        "src": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      }
```

How can I add it to the project and use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9643248/victoria-bernard do you think you can help?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in my install.json and it worked fine

```
 "resources": {
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "style",
        "src": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      },
      {
        "type": "style",
        "src": "./source/app.css"
      },
      {
        "type": "script",
        "src": "./source/app.js"
      }
    ]
  },

  "preview": {
    "handlers": [
      {
        "options": ["_default"],
        "execute": "INSTALL_SCOPE.setOptions(INSTALL_OPTIONS)"
      },
      {
        "options": ["_product"],
        "execute": "INSTALL_SCOPE.setProduct(INSTALL_PRODUCT)"
      }
    ]
  },
  "options": {}
}
```

There is likely something wrong with the JSON of your install.json. You could try copy and paste your install.json in this tool to test: https://www.cloudflare.com/apps/developer/install-json-tester

Comment: The install.json is valid but I get the following error on the preview section: An error occurred as we tried to bundle your apps to create a preview.
Please

Comment: Are all the files present in the source file? I would try removing all the resources and one by one add them back in to see which one is breaking. You could also check out the output of console.log. This isn't an issue with boot strap though